# multiple tenants accessing Confluent kafka on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, multi-tenant, confluent-platform

For multiple external tenants accessing Kafka, is there any issue with providing the same endpoint (ie. set of brokers, ports) to the multiple producers ?

what are the best practices wrt multiple tenants producing data on (Confluent) Kafka topics, Kafka being installed on GCP.

tia!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://cloud.devsite.corp.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/best-practices/enterprise-multitenancy) are Google's Best practices for enterprise multi-tenancy

Confluent Cloud is a fully managed Apache Kafka as a Service in the public cloud. Looks like you can register [here](https://www.confluent.io/resources/recommendations-developers-using-confluent-cloud/) to download the white paper that contain a guide to Kafka best practices.

As well you may find this [presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/ConfluentInc/fullymanaged-multitenant-kafka-clusters-tips-tricks-and-tools-christopher-beard-bloomberg-kafka-summit-2020) interesting.

Apache Kafka is available throw Google [Market Place](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/endpoints/payg-prod.gcpmarketplace.confluent.cloud).

Confluent is a [Google partner](https://cloud.google.com/partners/become-a-partner) and you can reach out to them [here](https://cloud.withgoogle.com/partners/detail/?id=confluent-inc) by clicking on the Contact partner button and filling the form.